# Google site: search operator returning conflicting results

Tags: web, sitemap, google-search, google-search-console

```
https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?rd=1
```

Based on the above link, I am able to see the indexed pages. However, I see varying results as below.

Are they supposed to return different results based on http protocols and/or trailing slashes as in example below?

```
site:https://www.desiza.com returns 26,800 results
site:https://www.desiza.com/ returns 21,000 results
site:www.desiza.com  returns 9640 results
site:www.desiza.com/ returns 4290 results
```

Which version is appropriate version? Thank you

Comment: The number of results Google returns is misleading - do not pay attention to it. You will never see more than 300-500 results.

Answer (score 0):

Google considers url with "/" and without "/" as two different urls. Similarly the case for http and https. Since the way it considers it returns different result sets for different queries. you can solve it either using rel="canonical" or doing a 301 redirect.